# Screenshot of the URL section of the browser

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I want to capture screenshot of the browser URL section.

```
browser.screenshot.save ('tdbank.png')
```

It will save the entire page of internal part of the browser, but I want to capture the URL header part of the browser.  Any suggestion?

Sometime, URL is saying http or https. I want to capture this in screenshot and archive it.  I know I could get it through,

```
url = browser.url
```

then do some comparison.  I need this for legal purpose and it should be done by taking a screenshot.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I've sometimes had the same problem.  I made a request that webdriver should include the url in the image metadata where that is possible (varies by image format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on windows, you could use the [`win32screenshot`](https://github.com/jarmo/win32screenshot) gem.  For example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'win32/screenshot'

b = Watir::Browser.new # using firefox as default browser
b.goto('http://www.example.org')
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:window, :title => /Firefox/).write("image.bmp")
b.close
```